# Cómo construir una pirámide de asteriscos validando que el número sea impar?

Tags: python

necesito ayuda, ya que tengo que hacer una pirámide de asterisco en Python, pero no se como validar que los números sean impares y en mi código, quiero que sea como en ese ejemplo, pero me sale numero de mas.

```
  # Si la base es 7:
  #   *
  #  ***
  # *****
  #*******

base = int(input('ingrese el tamaño de la base: ')) 
for tamanio_base in range(base):

espacios = base-tamanio_base -1
  asteriscos =  tamanio_base *2 -1
    print (' '*espacios+'*'*asteriscos)
```

Answer (score 0):

La siguiente expresión es `True` cuando el número `n` es impar:

```
n % 2 != 0
```

El operador `%` es el operador *módulo* que devuelve el resto de la división `n / 2`. Por tanto, si `n` es par, la división deja resto cero. Si el resto no es cero, el número es impar.

Puedes acortar más la comparación, ya que cero se considera `False` y cualquier otro valor `True`:

```
n % 2
```

La puedes usar en un `if`

```
if n % 2:
    print("impar")
```

o en un `while`

```
while n % 2:
    print("impar")
```